# DVDrw Drives locked in Read only mode Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: dvd

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on my PC and for some silly ass reason BOTH of my DVDrw Drives are coming up as read only.

How do I fix this.

1st(top) drive is a _NEC DVD+/-RW ND-3650A (105C)

2nd (bottom) drive is Optiarc DVD+/-RW AD-7230S (102B)

System is a Dell XPS720 Running Ubuntu 18.04.2 (Gnome 3.28.2)

This does not make much sense to me...

This computer was built on a fresh install using Ubuntu 18.04 on a bootable USB after a Motherboard and Processor upgrade.

Processor is an Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E6750 @ 2.66GHz × 2

Installed Ram is CORSAIR 1GB 240-Pin DDR2 SDRAM DDR2 667 (PC2 5300) Model

Please Help... I am at a loss and after combing these boards have not found a solution that makes sense... I am not an "IT" guy but rather a guy that is somewhat into tech and managed to rebuild this computer that I pulled out of a Trash can after My boss upgraded the office computers.

I would prefer to fix this thru the GUI but if I need to use the terminal I need a STEP-BY-STEP walk thru to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean in the first sentence. What do you mean by "coming up as read only"?

Comment: yes add a screenshot, press the `PrtScr` key.